# Getting a formula with a multi-cell reference to repeat with the reference starting after the end of the previous reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm hoping this is a simple problem to fix, but I've been unable to find a solution so far.

I'm trying take a long list of numbers and find the highest value of every group of 60.

It's very easy to find the highest value in a column, but how do I get the following formula to repeat?

```
=MAX(B1:B60)
```

How do I write the formula so that I can also find the maximum of `B61:B120` and so on down through the entire column?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in any column (`C` for example) and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill down the column:

```dart
=MAX(INDEX(B:B,1+60*(ROW()-1)):INDEX(B:B,60*ROW()))
```

Note that it's always better to use `INDEX()` instead of `INDIRECT()` as it is non-volatile. For small spreadsheets it doesn't make much of a difference, but for larger ones, volatile functions slow down the calculations. It's best to get in the habit of only using non-volatile functions. (Where possible, of course.)

Plus, more importantly, in this particular case (and in general), a formula with `INDIRECT()` will break if a column is inserted to the left of the target column.

Answer (score 0):

Now that it's clear what you are looking for, what you need is the following function:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("$B"&(60*ROW()-59)):INDIRECT("$B"&(60*ROW())))
```

Copy this into the first N rows into whatever column you select for the results, where N is the number of rows in column `B`, divided by 60.

The `INDIRECT()` function converts a string containing a cell reference into the cell contents, so the first two rows of the results column will resolve to:-

```
=MAX($B1:$B60)
=MAX($B61:$B120)
```

I have used the absolute column reference `$B` to emphasize that you can move to another column without affecting the results, though it is unnecessary, since the column references are in text, which will not be modified when the formula is copied to other cells.

Comment: Is this what you want? After submitting my answer I realised that your requirement could have other interpretations. Plus, you say you want the maximum of 60 numbers, but your formula spans 61 rows.

Comment: Thanks that did help get me closer to where I am trying to get. The one issue that I have now is that I have too much information. Ideally, I only want 1 Max for every 60 rows. If I drag the formula you gave me down all the way I get a Max for every row instead of 1 per 60 rows. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you have any insight on how I can change the formula to show me just a single Max per 60 rows I would appreciate it. I know I could copy and paste it every 60 rows, but that we be very time consuming considering I have tens of thousands of rows of data.

Comment: @AaronHooper - You still haven't clarified whether you want the maximum of every 60 rows or every 61, but I have tried to answer both. If you remove the ambiguity from your question, I can simplify my answer.

Comment: 60 is what I would like. Thank you so much for your help sir!